# How to calculate the total number of buckets that have "value" greater than 0?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have this query that calculates the number of events per bucket. How can I calculate the total number of buckets that have `value` greater than `0`?

```
GET myindex/_search?
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "PlateNumber": "111"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_intensity": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "Datetime",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_of_events": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "Monthday"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output that I get. The expected answer that I want to get is `26`, because there are totally 26 elements in buckets that have `value` greater than 0. Basically I do not need the output of all buckets, I only need this total number.

```
{
  "took": 237,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 98,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "daily_intensity": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1493596800000,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-02T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1493683200000,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1493769600000,
          "doc_count": 4,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-04T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1493856000000,
          "doc_count": 6,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 6
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1493942400000,
          "doc_count": 0,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494028800000,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-07T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494115200000,
          "doc_count": 5,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494201600000,
          "doc_count": 6,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 6
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-09T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494288000000,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-10T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494374400000,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-11T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494460800000,
          "doc_count": 0,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-12T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494547200000,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-13T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494633600000,
          "doc_count": 0,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-14T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494720000000,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-15T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494806400000,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-16T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494892800000,
          "doc_count": 0,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-17T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1494979200000,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-18T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495065600000,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-19T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495152000000,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-20T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495238400000,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-21T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495324800000,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495411200000,
          "doc_count": 5,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-23T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495497600000,
          "doc_count": 16,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 16
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495584000000,
          "doc_count": 4,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-25T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495670400000,
          "doc_count": 6,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 6
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-26T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495756800000,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-27T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495843200000,
          "doc_count": 5,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1495929600000,
          "doc_count": 4,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-29T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1496016000000,
          "doc_count": 5,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-30T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1496102400000,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-05-31T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1496188800000,
          "doc_count": 4,
          "count_of_events": {
            "value": 4
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bucket Script Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) & [Sum Bucket Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html) to achieve this. Try below query.

```
GET myindex/_search?
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "PlateNumber": "111"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_intensity": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "Datetime",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_of_events": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "Monthday"
          }
        },
        "check": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "count_of_events"
            },
            "script": "return (params.count > 0 ? 1 : 0)"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "bucket_count": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "daily_intensity>check"
      }
    }
  }
}
```